# ViewFlipper Animation twice

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am using 'ViewFlipper' in my application with built-in animation. In'ViewFlipper' i have two 'LinearLayout'. I want to start flipping on 'Button' click which is on 'ViewFlipper' 1st child. On 'Button' click, I want to flip view with animation. But problem is that, 1st view is flipping twice and then 2nd view is displayed.

Here is my xml code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.testingfragments.MainActivity">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">


        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:text="button 1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="abc"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this 'MainActivity' code

```
    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);

    int displayedChild = viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
    int childCount = viewFlipper.getChildCount();

    if (displayedChild == childCount - 1) {
        viewFlipper.stopFlipping();
    }

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (rating.getRating() != 0) {
                viewFlipper.startFlipping();

            }
        }
    });
```